# button and itemcommand event sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Background information**:

1. I have a SQL connected datalist, one of the columns is called `work_order`
2. In the datalist I have inserted a button `btn_Start`. The button is populated at the end of each set
3. The goal of the `btn_Start` is to do a database insert, the insert needs to includes the `work_order` value from the set of data the button is clicked in (so the insert can be tied to the work_order value.)

`btn_Start` code:

```
protected void btn_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nothanks"].ConnectionString))
    {
        String query = "INSERT INTO [TimeTest] ([Starttime], [Work_Order]) VALUES (@Starttime, @Work_Order)";

        using (SqlCommand CCC = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            CCC.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            CCC.Parameters.Add("@Starttime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
            CCC.Parameters.Add("@Work_Order", SqlDbType.Int).Value = lb_User1.Text.ToString();

            CCC.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

4. To grab text of the `work_order` column, I'm using the `itemcommand` event to propagate a label (`lb_User1`).

DataList1_ItemCommand` code:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
        DataList2.SelectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
        lb_User1.Text = (DataList2.SelectedItem.FindControl("Work_OrderLabel4") as Label).Text;
}
```

5. This works well, each time `btn_Start` is pushed, `lb_User1` is updated with the right information.

**The issue**: when `btn_Start` is clicked, both `btn_Start` and `DataList1_ItemCommand` fire. But `DataList1_ItemCommand` fires **after** `btn_Start`. Which means `lb_User1` isn't updated with the right info yet, and as such the insert fails to work as needed.

NOTES:

1. the `lb_User1` isn't needed, I planned to go direct to the SQL insert. `lb_User1` was used for code testing (so I can see what's going on)
2. My **objective** is to do the SQL insert with the grabbed data from datalist (`Work_OrderLabel4`). If I can accomplish this objective a better way that would also solve the issue.
3. `btn_Start` isn't going to be the only button in the datalist. One possible solution is go way from having two events and only doing things under the `itemcommand` event, but how do you separate out which button fires, without involving their respective events.

**Objective**: I'm trying to get each embedded start button to grab its corresponding `work_order` value for use in a SQL insert. The above is trying to accomplish this task, I'm almost there but I'm having the issue stated above. I'm open for other ways to accomplish this task (see picture of clarification)

[image]

**Additional Information:**

[image]

```
 protected void DL_Main_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString))
    {
        String query = "INSERT INTO [TimeTest] ([Starttime], [Work_Order]) VALUES (@Starttime, @Work_Order)";

        using (SqlCommand CCC = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            CCC.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            CCC.Parameters.Add("@Starttime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
         // All you need is the value of Work_OrderLabel4 of the selected item so just do it like this. 
            CCC.Parameters.Add("@Work_Order", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (DL_Main.SelectedItem.FindControl("Work_OrderLabel") as Label).Text;


            CCC.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

After Running
[image: After Running]

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do. Why when btn_Start is clicked, both are fired? Nothing from the code shows that.

Comment: The ItemCommand event is raised when any button is clicked in the DataGrid control. Nothing in the code makes that happen, its a function of itemcommand. As per my understating, this is needed so i grab the right label value, in the event that my datalist has more then one record, i need the corresponding button click to grab the right value for the work order.

Comment: I added in an objective section to help clarify what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @Itomship - Have a look at the code-behind - it has to show you how the event is hooked up. You can then use that to solve your problem (or at least you can post that code in your question).

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `btnStart` and put the code below in your `DataList1_ItemCommand`. The only line I changed is the one with my comment:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nothanks"].ConnectionString))
{
    String query = "INSERT INTO [TimeTest] ([Starttime], [Work_Order]) VALUES (@Starttime, @Work_Order)";

    using (SqlCommand CCC = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        CCC.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        CCC.Parameters.Add("@Starttime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

        // All you need is the value of Work_OrderLabel4 of the selected item so just do it like this. 
        CCC.Parameters.Add("@Work_Order", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (DataList2.SelectedItem.FindControl("Work_OrderLabel4") as Label).Text;
    }

    CCC.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Also, as a side note, please give your controls better names than DataList1. Perhaps DataListTimeTest since it deals with TimeTest table.

Comment: The code is correct but it comes up with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". All of the names are correct.

Comment: I don't understand your comment: what code is correct? Where are you getting that exception?

Comment: The code is correct, it terms of names and function. But for some reason it can't find the Work_OrderLabel4". But if i assign this same function to a button it works.

Comment: Well that's probably because DataList2.SelectedItem is not the item which has the Work_OrderLabel4. Are you still clicking the button to invoke this?

Comment: I added an Additional Information section to the post. This shows that i have all the names correct, but i still get this issue. Same names have been changed to make it cleaner. The button has no back code, and has no other function  then triggering the item_command.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Their is nothing else on the page, it is not embedded in anything like a multiview